# jQuery toggle on Internet Explorer 7. Position and height Problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, joomla

i made a simple script that hide/show a hidden div. The page automatically adjusts its height on Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

However on Internet Explorer 7, the div overlaps the contents at the bottom
I'm currently using Joomla as CMS. Where have i gone wrong ? I have tried including "position:relative" for the bottom contents but it isn't helping.

```
$j(idName).css({"opacity": "0"});
$j(idName).slideToggle('fast', function() { 
    $j(idName).animate({opacity:"1"}, function() {
        if(jQuery.browser.msie) {
            this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
            $j("#main-body").css("height","auto");
        }
    }); 

});
```

Visit http://educationtechnologysummit.com/sponsors-a-partners.html to get a clearer view

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit unclear about your question, but from the looks of it, I think the problem you are presenting is that when you mouseover a menu item in IE7 the menu div is hidden behind other elements. (the menu div that is hidden is shown through the jQuery slideToggle function)

It looks like you've included a z-index for the hidden divs, but you didn't specify the z-index for the other elements that it is supposed to overlap. IE7 may incorrectly be allowing elements with an undefined z-index to be layered over the menu items.

EDIT:
Add to your CSS this:

```
#menu-spacer{z-index:489;}
#main-body{z-index:489;}
```

Comment: I forgot to address your statement about including "position:relative" attribute - this just orients the x and y coordinates of the element relative to the parent element along the plane of the screen, it doesn't designate whether an element will appear in front of or behind another element.

Comment: I removed position:relative  and added the css as suggested by you. They don't seem to help though. Apparently, the layers at the #bottom layer appears to be static !

Comment: I really appreciate that you're taking time to help me out here .. Thanks alot !

Comment: :) Can you please clarify for me the IDs of the elements in question? Or better yet, can you post a screenshot? I am using IE9 with Browser Mode set to IE7 so I just want to make sure we're not addressing the wrong elements

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS should work fine in IE7 if you remove the `position: relative` style from the .wrapper class in template.css (or, remove the .wrapper class entirely).

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your css. "position:relative"